# Boolean truthiness narrowing not working in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I've checked similar questions and cannot find any examples like mine. I am using a function to narrow down a boolean option in an if/else clause, but it only works when defined explicitly, not using the function.

Here is the code I am working with—

#### TYPES

```
type SimpleCellContent = string | number;
type ComplexCellContent = {
  content: SimpleCellContent;
  formatter: (content: any) => string;
  class?: string;
  link?: string;
  linkClass?: string;
};
type CellContent = SimpleCellContent | ComplexCellContent;
```

#### LOGIC

```
const isSimpleContent = (cellData: CellContent) => {
  return typeof cellData === 'string' || typeof cellData === 'number' || typeof cellData === 'undefined';
};

const extractContent = (cellData: CellContent) => {
  if (isSimpleContent(cellData)) {
    return cellData;
  } else if (typeof cellData.content !== 'undefined') { // <---  ERROR !!! 
    return cellData.content;
  } else {
    throw new Error('Invalid cell data: ' + JSON.stringify(cellData));
  }
};
```

The error reads…

```
Property 'content' does not exist on type 'CellContent'.
  Property 'content' does not exist on type 'string'. ts(2339)
```

---

However, if I switch `isSimpleContent(cellData)` to be the exact same return value of the previous function (`typeof cellData === 'string' || typeof cellData === 'number' || typeof cellData === 'undefined'`), it works without an issue.

Why wouldn't this work the same way when using a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless there are new developments in the language, a function only becomes a type guard, if you explicitly mark it in the return type:

```
const isSimpleContent = (cellData: CellContent): cellData is SimpleCellContent => {
  return typeof cellData === 'string' || typeof cellData === 'number' || typeof cellData === 'undefined';
};
```

Docs:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates